# Converting String ="0xfbff0000" to int value for using it in Layout.setBackground(int i);

Tags: android, string, layout, integer, background-color

Now, this might seem fairly simple at first, but took good amount of time of mine.
`Integer.valueOf(0xfbff0000)` wouldn't work, neither would the `ParseInt` work , i am desperately looking for a solution here.

The Exceptions I get while converting them is NUMBERFORMAT Exception.

I need to use this Hexadecimal value to set background of my layout Dynamically

i.e. `Layout.setBackground(int)`

Let me clarify that I have a String Variable that looks like `String backgroundColor="0xfbff0000";`

need this variable `backgroundColor` to be used as Integer in the `Layout.Setbackground(int)`

Comment: whats that..? hexa decimal value for color or resource id..

Comment: Its a hexadecimal color not from the Resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [Color.parseColor(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor%28java.lang.String%29) but you need to replace 0x prefix with #

For instance:

```
Color.parseColor("#fbff0000");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new Color().parseColor(colorString)
```

split that string and remove `0x` and put the rest in above methods args..

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
int i = Integer.valueOf(myHexString, 16).intValue();
```

Comment: No, I get the same exception Number Format Exception